Determining proper correction factor between estimated and actual values.
I have two different types of radiation dosimeters monitoring dose over a designated time frame.
One is an electronic dosimeter which displays dose received in real time. The final measurement at the end of the monitoring period is the sum of multiple measurements recorded during the monitoring period. This value does not account for background radiation subtraction or statistical error and is considered to be an estimate.
The other is a NVLAP "officially certified" dosimeter which can only be read at the end of the monitoring period. It is a continuous measurement of dose received across the monitoring period. The end result is corrected for background radiation as well as expected statistical error. It is considered to be the actual measurement of dose received for the entire monitoring period.
Within the monitoring period we have a window of estimates for which we want to determine a corrected actual value using a correction factor derived from the results received at the end of the monitoring period. The relationship between the window values and end values is considered to be linear.
Let's say:
Total.estimate = 100
Total.actual = 80
Window.estimate = 20
Window.actual = X
One coworker thinks we should do a simple ratio to find the actual dose received in that window of time.
window.actual = window.estimate * total.actual / total.estimate
X = 20 * 80 / 100 = 16
Another thinks this is incorrect given that the dosimeter providing the actual value is held to a higher statistical significance. We should instead do
window.actual = window.estimate * (1 - ((total.estimate - total.actual) / total.actual))
X = 20 * (1 - ((100 - 80) / 80)) = 15
Which is correct? And why?
